# Species with natural Hex-Decimal processing capacity

Tags: biology

How advanced a species will be if it has natural capacity to process hexadecimal notation.Suppose we can conduct a simulated experiment with two species, one near human with capacity to process decimal numbers side by side to a species capable of hex-decimal notation(on a side note ,How might such occur in nature). Which species will come on top For the purpose imagine that both species descended from same ancestor.There is an question "base-12 numeral system" [base-12 numeral system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9741/base-12-numeral-system.Mine) is different because I am asking about completely natural number processing Without any need of culture.

Comment: As soon as a species can count and process symbols, it is irrelevant what symbols. So the only distinction you are left with is a reason to count in a base-16 system - and the obvious answer to that is having 8 fingers on each 'hand' (or 4 *bronxies* on each of your 4 *falders*, etc). [See this question for base-12](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9741/base-12-numeral-system) for inspiration (voting to close as a duplicate of that one)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise is faulty and it’s answered with a short comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base-12 numeral system](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9741/base-12-numeral-system)

Comment: There is no reason why this kind of processing should make a species advanced in any regard. You can teach a human to count like that. Taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal): "The traditional Chinese units of weight were base-16"

Comment: All you have to do is suggest why they chose base 16 over a more common base 60.

Comment: @Jan Doggen That's my question "As soon as a species can count and process symbols". How soon  a could  species progress if it is able to progress 16 symbols compared to a species which has learned to process 10 symbols.How soon could be soon.@JDługosz can you point fault in my question.

Comment: @carrottop There is no difference in learning base-10, base-16 or any other base for that matter. Just change the culture. Every normal human on our earth today would be able to "process" base-16 if you teach him as a kid. There would be no difference in processing capacitiy or anything else, except for difficulties in our society, because we are used to base-10 in most cases.

Comment: One of the first things I learned when starting a course as mathematics teacher was working in base 8 (so I would understand how math felt to children). Doing everything in base 8 for a few days is enough to get really comfortable with it. The same applies to other bases.

Comment: "Which species will come on top" -- The success of a species is independent of its number system. For that matter, humans use base-16 math all the time in computers and I don't see the computer savvy either taking over the world or being driven to extinction..

Comment: @erik base 12 is better :)  but interestingly, I did the same when my son started adding and subtracting. Also, if you haven't considered it already, an abacus is an excellent way to learn about carrying, positional significance and orders of magnitude

Comment: question seems clear to me, even if its awkwardly phrased. Isn't he asking if one counting base gives an evolutional advantage over another?

Comment: @Innovine OP seems to be assuming it does and is asking how big the advantage would be. The answer then is "none, because it doesn't matter", which the OP does not seem to agree with.

Comment: @erik "which species comes out on top" doesn't sound like an assumption, but a question to me. I tend to agree with the 'none' answer. But evolution can work some very subtle magic so I wouldn't be surprised by an advantage either.. slightly mor efficient math leads to better deals, leads to improved economy, leads to many improvements and advantages... look at algorithmic short trading for a very measurable effect, the time taken for packets to travel on the network can mean millions of dollars, whicheis why traders place routers at major network nodes and pay crazy high rent for it.

Comment: @Erik issue is not about my agreeing or disagreeing, If  my logic is wrong then so be it. I will accept  my fault.My issue is that everybody here is thinking from the Mathematical  or Cultural point of view I am looking at  this issue from the biological point of view. Does extremely primitive species developed Hex-Decimal base system by chance what could be its developmental trajectory?Since We have Humans as the only control I used decimal system as example.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using base 12 (the duodecimal system) instead of 16. Base 12 has the advantage that you can divide 12 into half, thirds and quarters evenly. It makes for a more convenient everyday counting system, and there are no drawbacks. 
Our clock face is base 12, as is the year, as is inches to a foot, and troy weights (measurements of gold and gems).

Unfortunately base 10 has proven difficult to shake off in general, but this is due to convention and habit only, not anything intrisic to the numeric base.

Comment: We have only 10 digits so that's why it's difficult to shake off. If we had started with 12 digits maybe we'd only have base 12, but unfortunately we have 10 fingers so it's why we made base 10.

Comment: You are putting the cart before the horse. *the advantage that you can divide by* is derived from the base, not the other way around.

Comment: @JanDoggen please clarify, it is not clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: @JanDoggen 12 just happens to be 2x2x3 which is why it has a lot of divisors compared to 10 which is just 2x5. In any base, divisions over any of the prime factors of the base are more easy; there is a genuine advantage in picking a base with a lot of prime factors (like 12, or 60)

Comment: My point is that when a species develops a counting system through evolution, this will happen before any considerations about 'handy divisors' (elementary counting developes ages before calculus/math does)

Comment: @JanDoggen obviously not in all cases, since I just provided several examples which show the exact opposite. You could could count without base at all, just making notches on a belt, and Add and Divide these without ever having a defined base. Romans were counting and performing math with their numeral system which isn't set to a strict base at all (elements of base 2, 5 and 10 abound in it). Base 10 only came in long after, with the introduction of decimal writing of numbers, and even this was met with a degree of resistance.

Comment: Base 12 is also much more convenient for packing, which is e.g. 6-packs of beer & soda, or a dozen eggs, are much more common than 5 or 10 packs.

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal means base 16.

There's no intrinsic value to base 16 over base 10 mathematically.  It might lead you to find the binary system earlier, but the binary system doesn't, in and of itself, give you any advantage over anything else.

In terms of developing technology and science, you still have to develop all the stuff leading up to computer technology to get to have any real practical use for the binary system or hexadecimal numbers.  And hexadecimal or any other related system makes no difference as by it's nature pure mathematics is abstracted away from base system.

It's worth noting that the use of different bases in human counting systems is very common.  We use base 12 and 16 in various measuring systems and we still use base 7, 12, 24, 60 and 365 in mixed base calculations of time every day - you do, I do, everyone does.  So human brains are quite capable of handling arbitrary bases in quite complex ways without special training beyond primary school !

Once you teach a system early it gets widespread use early and become quite natural.

I can think of only one piece of mathematics that uses base 16 explicitly and that's an algorithm designed to produce successive hexadecimal digits of $\pi$, but beyond generating millions of digits of $\pi$ (which is not really useful in practice) it just shows someone was very clever, rather than anything else.   In practice the discovery that $\pi$ is irrational is more important and the discovery of various approximations (like $\frac {22} 7$) is more useful, none of which requires hexadecimal or benefits from it.  Likewise $e$ or $\sqrt 2$ and so on.

So your hexadecimal aware people are no different from ours and won;t, IMO, do any better than we do.

Comment: I know we use different base methods in our daily life.But I was talking about natural processing.We can't naturally process base 60 or 24 We may be able to process 7 or 20.We require culture and somewhat sophisticated across generation knowledge transfer to achieve that.

Comment: It's been argued before that an early discovery of binary numbers would lead to an earlier development of boolean algebra, which would in turn accelerate the development of logic circuits and then computers. using hex doesn't mean an earlier understanding of binary though.

Comment: @carrottop we can't naturally process base 10 either. We need to learn to do so.

Comment: There's nothing natural about using a positional base-10 number system (or base-whatever), only a natural tendency to use body parts to count. If you'd been trained to use hexadecimal, it would feel absolutely natural to you.

Comment: I would rather think that being born with the ability to process base-16 numbers would be a disadvantage if you couldn't adapt to (and learn) other systems as we humans do thanks to society and culture.

Comment: There is a theory that Romans and Greeks have stumbled upon computing.But they couldn't find its practical use because unwieldy Roman numeral system.But I can teach you count on your fingers in fifteen minutes simply by demonstration.Can you teach me without elaborate symbols.

Comment: We has [abaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus) for most of our recorded history, and that about as complex a computing device as was practical in Roman and Greek times.  The technological limitations would not be different just because you use base 16.

Comment: @carrottop the issues in the Roman system stemmed from not having any base at all. Once you pick a base-system, the exact one doesn't really matter. You can teach the same finger-counting on one hand and teach base 5. You can teach the same finger-counting on hands and feet, ignoring the thumbs and big toes, and do base 16.

Comment: My argument is that mathematics and science does not depend on what base system you use.  The underlying theory and practice is symbolic and independent of base.  A choice of base should therefore have no effect on the development of a technological culture,  I can't speak for the Roman choice of base, but it didn't hold them back in engineering if that's the case,

Comment: Nobody is denying the achievement of Romans or anybody.The issue is what did not happen due to lack of efficient base system.The AntiKythera Mechanism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism